# How to make transparent WMS vector background in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

I have a WMS vector layer added to QGIS desktop.
But the background is not transparent - it is white.
How to change that?
When I add this WMS to ArcGIS - all is just fine.

Here is the WMS link:

```
http://maps.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/services/Cadastre/CadastreWMS/MapServer/WMSServer?
```

Comment: Which outputformat did you select when you added the layer into QGIS?

Comment: Yeah, it was default set to jpeg. When set to PNG it works fine. Add an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WMS servers can typically serve images in many formats (jpeg, 8-bit png, 24-bit png etc.). Jpeg format, while it gives a good compression rate for natural looking imagery like aerial photos or satellite images, has a drawback that it does not support transparency.

If you need WMS layers with transparency, use png instead of jpeg as an outputformat. For vector layers png is a good choice anyways because such layers can usually be compressed as effectively with png as with jpeg. Png is also a lossless compression method which keeps the lines on the map sharp.